# Connect to Unix using ssh and sftp via Java [RSA SecuerID token]

Tags: java, unix, ssh, rsa, sftp

I need to connect to Unix Server using **Java** via **SSH** and **SFTP** protocol and execute specific commands and do File Transfers also. But there is RSA token authentication is enabled on Unix. So I need to get the current **RSA token password** at run time also along with User's Password.
So how to get this done
 via Java? Is there any Java API for this?

FYI, Unix Login steps using putty :

1. connect using Server IP.
2. List item
3. give User Name.
4. give Password
5. give the 6 digit SecurID generated Number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like keyboard-interactive authentication. In this authentication mechanism the server asks user a question, to which the user must respond. Any number of questions is possible and their order is defined by the server.

Keyboard-interactive authentication is used by many servers, but it's usually reduced to asking for a password, so most software which claims support for this authentication method will just put a password as the answer and that's all.

I don't know if free Java libraries support keyboard-interactive authentication with multiple questions. Our [SecureBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/java-sftp.php) classes have an event which passes questions to the application, and the application can either provide an answer itself or ask the human operator to provide the answer.