# Run plink version of PuTTY from Java

Tags: java, cmd, process, putty

I am writing a java code to run `PuTTY` by using the `plink` version of it which is a command line implementation of `PuTTY`.

I used the Process Builder to run it from cmd and the connection from `plink` gets established. But I wasn't able to send the linux commands to it to run on the server and after checking it's working in an actual command prompt, I found out that after the command to open `plink`, there is a new process created. So I am guessing to make my commands work on plink I need to find that process and then send commands to it.

This is my code so far which establishes the connection using plink.

```
import java.io.*;

public class RunCmdCommandsStackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String cmd1 = new String("plink -ssh hostname -P 2222 -l username -pw password");
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", cmd1);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) { break; }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to run linux commands on the server after creating a connection in the java code.

I have already tried to create a connection using the `Jsch` package but the security settings on my server seem to prohibit me from accessing it using that. `PuTTY` works fine for this and `plink` is also working fine in a regular `cmd` window.

Comment: Use native Java SSH library, like JSch, instead of driving a console application.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have written there that I have already tried JSch but it doesn't even establish the connection. Seems like there are security settings to prevent it on the comapny servers. Which is why I tried to use a console app.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice. Though it makes no sense. While a server can indeed decide to *close connection* based on a client library/software, it cannot *reject connection* based on that. As at connection time, it cannot know yet, what the client is like. Moreover, there's nothing that prevents you from faking Plink in JSch. => Show us your JSch code as well as a [log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47411185/850848).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The server has RSA Token based authentication system. I tried it many times to connect using JSch and tried multiple solutions to the problems I faced which other people had too and many solutions worked for them too. But not for me unfortunately, it didn't work for me. I had asked a specific question for the JSch issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51166570/connect-to-a-linux-system-secured-by-rsa-securid-using-ssh2-in-java

Comment: @MartinPrikryl someone else asked a similar question which according to me didn't get the solution I can use. Maybe you can help out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439517/connect-to-unix-using-ssh-and-sftp-via-java-rsa-secuerid-token